# Is the barycenter of a convex curve in $\mathbb R^2$ Lipschitz with respect to the Hausdorff distance?

Tags: metric-spaces, plane-curves, convex-geometry

For a curve $C$, its barycenter is
$$\text{Bar}(C) = \frac{1}{\text{length}(C)}\int\limits_C x d \mathcal H^1(x).$$
Does there exist a constant $L$ such that for $C_1,C_2$ *convex* curves in the plane, $$|\text{Bar}(C_1) - \text{Bar}(C_2)| \leq L d_H(C_1,C_2),$$ where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance?

Comment: I do not have time to think about this, but take a look at Lee's solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760769/why-is-the-barycenter-operation-in-hadamard-spaces-lipschitz-continuous/1774840#1774840): First use it for convex polygonal curves and see if you can get some uniform estimates.

Comment: I don't follow. The sum of the distances between vertices of convex polygonal curves could be much greater than their Hausdorff distance. Take, e.g., the polygonal curves with vertices $(-1,0),(0,\epsilon),(1,0)$ and $(-1,0),(1,\epsilon),(1,0)$.

Comment: This question has been posted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343122/is-the-barycenter-of-a-convex-plane-curve-lipschitz-with-respect-to-the-hausdorf), where it has been answered.